# Attempt to present controller whose view is not in the hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to accomplish what I think is a pretty common set of steps:

When my app starts, load a home controller in a navigation controller:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.window = window
    return true
}
```

When my app loads check if the user is logged in.  If not, present a registration view controller:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if ref.loggedIn != nil {
        // user authenticated
        print(ref.userData)
    } else {
        // No user is signed in
        let registerViewController = RegisterViewController()
        if let navController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            navController.presentViewController(registerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

In my RegisterViewController, provide a button that switches to a LoginViewController:

```
@IBAction func login(sender: UIButton) {
        print("LOGIN")
        let loginViewController = LoginViewController()
        // How do I present the view controller here?
    }
```

My question is: how can I present the LoginViewController so that calling `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)` will return to my HomeViewController?

Things I've tried:

- If I call `self.presentViewController` from the `RegisterViewController` then dismissing returns back to the `RegisterViewController` instead of `HomeViewController`
- If I try to get a reference to rootViewController via `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` and present the login controller on rootViewController then I get an error "Attempt to present ... on ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you will get the error "Attempt to present ... on ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

First you need to make the instance of ViewController using storyboard identifier.

Please try this :-

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewControllerToBePresented") as! UIViewController //use your class name here to cast it.
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> EDIT
>
> In your case you can use protocol on register screen which will get
>   implemented on home screen.
>
> And in that implementation you can write code to dismiss register view
>   and then present Login view.

Comment: I'm using xib files and am not using the storyboard.  I do have an instance of a view controller already.  I can call self.presentViewController from RegisterViewController but that presents the view on top of the registration view controller rather than the HomeViewController.

Comment: @EricConner If you are presenting RegisterViewController  then it will get presented on top of registration view Controller only.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there a way I can swap the LoginViewController with RegisterViewController so that it gets presented on top of the HomeViewController?  Or is there another way to go about doing this?

Comment: Can you tell me your screen hierarchy.  May be and image explaining your hierarchy of screens

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to present a new view controller add that view controller in navigation controller and then present the navigation controller..
From the presented view controller you can dismiss to previous view controller.
I hope this will work..

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use protocol on register screen which will get implemented on home screen.

And in that implementation you can write code to dismiss register view and then present Login view.